# Parsing a string by using regex

Tags: regex, typescript, regex-greedy

I need to parse an input string that has the format of

`AB~11111, AB~22222, AB~33333, AB~44444`

into separate strings:

`AB~11111`, `AB~22222`, `AB~33333`, and `AB~44444`

Here is my attempted Regex:

```
range = "([^~,\n]+~[^,]+,)?";
non_delimiter = "[^,\n;]+";
range_regex = new RegExp(this.range + this.non_delimiter, 'g');
```

But somehow this regex would only parse the input string into

`AB~11111, AB~22222` and `AB~33333, AB~44444`

instead of parsing the input string into individual strings.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen TypeScript

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is missing the boat, but from your input what about something like:

```
AB~\d+
```

This should match each of the strings from the above: https://regex101.com/r/vVFDIG/1. And if there's variation (i.e., it can be other letters) then maybe something like:

```
[A-Z]{2}~\d+
```

Or whatever it would need to be but using the negative character class seems like quite a roundabout way of doing it. If that's the case, you could just do:

```
[^ ,]+
```

Comment: If there are always five digits you could also change `\d+` into `\d{5}`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a regex split here on `,\s*`:

```js
var input = "AB~11111, AB~22222, AB~33333, AB~44444";
var parts = input.split(/,\s*/);
console.log(parts);
```

If you need to check that the input also consists of CSV list of `AB~11111` terms, then you may use `test` to assert that:

```js
var input = "AB~11111, AB~22222, AB~33333, AB~44444";
console.log(/^[A-Z]{2}~\d{5}(?:,\s*[A-Z]{2}~\d{5})*$/.test(input));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't just do this, since it also needs to make sure that the input string has the format of AB~11111.

Comment: @Leila You should check the format separately, q.v. my updated answer which uses string `test` to do this.